# Installed phonegap from node.js, now how do i connect it to visual studio 2010?

Tags: cordova

The phone gap documentation for VS 2010 is horrible.

I have windows phone sdk installed, vs 2010 installed, downloaded node js.  I ran the phonegap installer from nodejs.

What do i do from here?  Where is cordovastarter.x.x..xzip?  lib\windows-phone\ is no where to be found.

Download the latest copy of [PhoneGap and extract its contents. We will be working with the subfolder: lib\windows-phone\

Comment: I am currently having this issue as well have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a new project called "hello"

```
cordova create hello
```

2) Get inside the folder

```
cd hello
```

3) Add required platform. I assume you want WP8 project.

```
cordova platform add wp8
```

After these steps, check in "hello\platforms\".

Comment: This does not work, I am actually trying to use this for android as well... any ideas?